# Special chars in REST-Route

Tags: c#, rest, url, asp.net-web-api

I´ve got a REST-Source which is `localhost/admin/users/{userName}` but my user has a '.' in it, so I can´t pass it through the route.

My Question is how to pass spezial chars through a REST-API?

I tried to escape the '.' with %2E but the RESTed extension for Firefox tells me the route does not exist.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("users/{userName}")]
        public User GetUser(string userName)
        {
            // some logig here

            return new User(userName);
        }
```

I hoped to find a way to escape such chars :-/

Comment: This is just a URL. `REST` is a set of principles, not a specification or protocol. Your question is simply "How do I URL-encode a string"? The *server* code doesn't have to do anything. It's the *client* code that needs to URL-encode the `username` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a trailing slash `/` to the URL if it contains a dot `.`:

```
localhost/admin/users/{userName}/
```

The API sees the `.` and thinks you're trying to access a file. Adding a trailing slash should fix this.

Comment: Ok, so in that case if I have an API with parameter between like: localhost/admin/{config}/all there will be no problem with '.'?

Comment: I've tested it for my API and it works but you would need to test it for your own API and configuration to make sure.